# How can I traverse a list with specific probability?

Tags: c#, foreach, probability

Suppose, I have a list:

```
List<Point2d> listOfCoordinates = new List<Point2d>();
```

Suppose, this list has 15 elements. I.e. `listOfCoordinates.Count == 15`.

Suppose, I want to print the items in the list with specific probabilities. I.e. if I run, say, 1000 iterations, **1st** five elements should be printed 30% of the time(probability = 0.30); the **middle** five elements should be printed 50% of the time (probability = 0.50), and the **last** five elements should be printed 20% of the time (probability = 0.20).

Remember that, the probability is stored in `Point2d` class as a double value. I.e.

```
class Point2d
{
    public double X, Y, Probability;
}
```

Therefore, I can't manipulate the looping statements to achieve this.

How can I run a `foreach` loop to achieve this?

Comment: So printing each element is an independent event? From the way you worded it, it sounded like the first element being printed and the last element being printed are mutually exclusive, but your edit suggests otherwise.

Comment: And after those 1000 iterations, you expect *around* 5000 elements to be printed. Did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming printing each `Point2d` is an independent event, with probability `Probability`, and you have a list such as:

```
var list = new List<Point2d> {
    // first 5 all have probability 0.3
    new(1, 2, 0.3),
    new(3, 4, 0.3),
    new(5, 6, 0.3),
    new(7, 8, 0.3),
    new(9, 10, 0.3),
    // middle 5 all have probability 0.5
    new(11, 12, 0.5),
    new(13, 14, 0.5),
    new(15, 16, 0.5),
    new(17, 18, 0.5),
    new(19, 20, 0.5),
    // last 5 all have probability 0.2
    new(21, 22, 0.2),
    new(23, 24, 0.2),
    new(25, 26, 0.2),
    new(27, 28, 0.2),
    new(29, 30, 0.2)
};
```

You can print them out like this:

```
void Print(List<Point2d> list, Random random) {
    foreach (var point in list) {
        if (random.NextDouble() < point.Probability) {
            Console.WriteLine(point);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that [`NextDouble`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.nextdouble?view=net-6.0#system-random-nextdouble) returns a value before 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive).

Doing 1000 iterations will give you about 5000 lines:

```
var random = new Random();
for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++) {
    Print(list, random);
}
```

Comment: Can you kindly explain `if (random.NextDouble() < point.Probability)`? How does this fulfill our objective?

Comment: *it sounded like the first element being printed and the last element being printed are mutually exclusive,* --- Can you show me this case, too?

Comment: Perhaps I should have added that `Random.NextDouble` generates a *uniformly* distributed random number? Does that make more sense now? @user366312

Comment: @user366312 No, that's not possible with just a list of `Point2d`. You would also need extra information about how the points are "grouped" together, if you know what I mean.

Comment: *You would also need extra information about how the points are "grouped" together if you know what I mean.* --- My given example scenario is designed as the rolling of a die. Can you explain what alternative you were thinking about?

Comment: @user366312 In your wording, you seem to refer to "groups" of points, such as "first 5", "middle 5" and "last 5". What I meant was, if you want to treat those groups as independent events, rather than the individual points as independent events, then you would need something else to encode the groups. The simplest alternative would probably be a `List<List<Point2d>>` to model the groups. (There is a possibility that I totally misunderstood you and this doesn't make any sense at all for what you are doing)